# Deal cards in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

I need to define a function

```
deal :: [String] -> [String] -> [(String,String)]
```

It needs to work like this:

```
deal ["Hercule","Ariadne"] ["Ace","Joker","Heart"] -- Outputs [("Ace","Hercule"),("Joker","Ariadne"),("Heart","Hercule")]
take 4 (deal ["a","b","c"] (map show [0..]))       -- Outputs [("0","a"),("1","b"),("2","c"),("3","a")]
deal ("you":(repeat "me")) ["1","2","3","4"]       -- Outputs [("1","you"),("2","me"),("3","me"),("4","me")]
```

Also, to be quite honest, this is an exercise; I am advised to use `zip` and `cycle`.

I already tried to solve this for three and a half hours, yet failed to find the solution.

Q: Would you give me a hint how to approach this problem?

**My best attempt**

```
deal :: [String] -> [String] -> [(String, String)]
deal ps cs = dealHelper ps cs ps cs []
  where dealHelper [] [] _ _ result = result
        dealHelper ps [] _ _ result = dealHelper ps (take (length ps) cs) result
        dealHelper [] cs allps allcs result = dealHelper (take (length cs))
```

(That does not even compile.)

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: The advice points out the functions you need. `cycle [a,b,c] = [a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c,...]` repeats the same list elements forever. You have two input lists: players and cards. Which one should be used repeatedly? Start by using `cycle` on that. Also note that `zip` takes two lists, and if one of them is finite but the other is infinite then the output will stop once the finite list is over.

Answer (score 1):

Solution turned out to be:

```
deal :: [String] -> [String] -> [(String,String)]
deal ps cs = zip cs (cycle ps)
```